# What could cause a C++Builder / Delphi thread and application to not shut down?

Tags: windows, multithreading, delphi, c++builder, shutdown

Once, during testing, my C++Builder / Delphi application raised an uncaught exception in a background worker thread.  [EurekaLog](http://www.eurekalog.com/index_delphi.php) caught the exception and sent an error report, as I expected, and everything appeared to be okay.

However, when I closed the application's main window, something remained running in the background, because the application was still listed in the task manager (and still had resources open).

I've tried to duplicate this problem, by deliberately introducing various bugs in the background worker thread, but I can't.

What could cause a thread and application to remain running like this, even after the main window has closed (and, presumably, PostQuitMessage has been called)?

How can I ensure that the application always cleanly shuts down?

Comment: Do you have any EnterCriticalSection code that could block endlessly? That's a really common deadlock to get right at shutdown, right there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first rule is that threads main executor methods should be written so that they can be signalled and shut down properly, and the second rule is that you shouldn't just shut down your app's main thread first, and then hope that the other threads shut down in their own time, to be safe, you should signal  all the background threads to stop, wait for that shutdown to complete, and THEN shutdown your main thread. A minimal THREAD example:

```
procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
   Init;
   while not Terminated do
      OneWorkItem; // inside OneWorkItem, you  ALSO need to check for Terminated
end;
```

A minimal main form/main-thread example:

```
   procedure TMyMainForm.CheckAndShutdown;
   begin
     if FPendingShutdownFlag then 
       if AllBackgroundThreadsTerminated then 
             Self.Close;
   end;
```

You could set FPendingShutdownFlag and have the function above called from the application idle processing loop.  When you have the user click the main form FormClose, if AllBackgroundThreadsTerminated returns false, set CanClose to false, and set the `FPendingShutdownFlag := true` instead.

If you make an endless loop (while true), the application does not shut down cleanly, even if it looks like that to you.   Somehow, the application is terminated, and the running threads may just suddenly go away quietly, or they may deadlock or otherwise fail on you, as they may be using resources in thread 2 that you are busy freeing in thread 1.

You may have one or more intentional race conditions because you might not have written your thread execute method to be interruptable, or you may start the closing of the main application thread and the VCL and its objects, before you are sure that your background threads are completely shut down.

Comment: I must not have explained myself well enough.  I did my best to write my threads to be interruptible, to check for TThread.Terminated, to avoid deadlocks and resource problems, etc.  Somehow, once, in spite of that, my application did not terminate; it remained running in the background even though its form had closed.  I'd like to know why and how to prevent it.  I did everything I could think of to duplicate that error state (including adding an endless while(true) loop), so that I figure out how to recover from it, but I still can't duplicate the error state.

Comment: Then it sounds like you are searching for an elusive race-condition or other similar intermittent asynchronous failures in your code. Do you have any TThread.Synchronize calls that might be blocking for a long time? Do you have any Sleep() calls?  You might have what I call a "sleeping beauty" problem, for example.  Background threads must be completely shut down before you shut down the main thread, if the background threads use ANY objects at all or state that the main thread is going to free.

Comment: It seems to me that you should start out by instrumenting your code with a lot of outputdebugstring messages, and then running it on the client system where the code fails, along with MS DebugView (an outputdebugstring viewer) and seeing what parts of the code are reached, or not reached, on the client system.

Comment: Well, IF the background work threads do not share any data directly with main-thread controls etc, eg. both only ever access data that outlives the controls/threads, (this effectively means no synchronize(), no TThread.waitFor(), no OnTerminate() ), then it is not necessary to wait for background threads to terminate before the main thread forms etc. are destroyed, finalization sections run and the main thread exits.  The main thread will eventually call ExitProcess() and all background threads will be destroyed by the OS, no matter what state they are in.

Comment: I haven't yet tracked down the problem (it's _extremely_ rare), but you've given me some good information on things to check.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that worker thread terminated, and main thread is not waiting for it to finish?

Comment: I'm not sure what happened, and I've only seen this problem once, but I'd like to make sure it doesn't recur on a customer's machine.  If I deliberately make the worker thread never terminate (by adding a "while (true);" loop in C++), the application still shuts down cleanly, so I don't think the problem is just that the main thread is waiting on the worker to terminate.

Comment: Wait a minute. You added a while loop that ensures that the thread never terminates. But somewhere else can call TThread.Terminate. So what you've done is make it not very likely that it would shut down CLEANLY. No wonder your app is broken.

Comment: @Warren P: I think you may have misunderstood.  See my comment on your answer.